# Magicento not working fine in PHPStorm IDE

Tags: magento-1.9, phpstorm

I recently installed PHPStorm and Magicento plugin to develop new magento extension but it doesn't works fine for me when i press ( alt + M ) it say that Magicento is disabled, when i check it in the plugins It's enabled (It's trail version )
[image: Configuration of Magicento in PhpStorm IDE]

[image: Magicento is disabled]

Comment: Please help me if anyone has saw similar kind of issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251030/magicento-notification-error-requesting-trial-license-please-try-again-later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have enabled Magicento for the current projet ?
The second screenshot seem to be "Template Project Settings" and not "Projet Settings [YOURPROJECT]".

Try going into Project Settings with CTRL+ALT+S or File -> Settings".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that you trial version is expired.